# Highlighted Content custom query to find subdirectory contents

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, modern-experience, caml, highlighted-content-web-part

I'm trying to filter the results of the Highlighted Content web part a bit more than is available in their pre-built filters.

I'm in Office 365 (corporate) and my SharePoint page is in the same group as the files I want to display. For the life of me I cannot figure out this custom query.

The files:

- PDFs
- All filenames have (WI_PIP) at the start of the file name
- Are nested inside a few folders (Group Name / Documents / Group One / WI / PIP)

Any help is greatly appreciated. The goal is to only show the PDF files within the PIP folder. I'm confused on how to handle spaces in folder names as well in these queries.

Here is what I have so far, but the web part simply displays the three folders within Documents, nothing else.

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="FileDirRef" />
            <Value Type="Text">/Group Name/Documents/Group One/WI/PIP</Value>
        </Eq>
    </Where>
</Query>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom query like this:

```
Path: "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/SharedDocuments/General" FileType: pdf
```

Use correct folder URL in `Path`.

**Example**:

[image]

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Thank you!

Comment: I am having similar issue, but when i put both properties together it doesnt returns anythhing, separately they are working :( any advice?

Comment: and it is only happening with image file types i.e. png, jpeg, jpg

Comment: can you show the query you used?

Comment: **Path:"https://myweb.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/Shared%20Documents/General" FileType:PNG**

if i add pdf or xlsx or pptx it starts working

Comment: It works for me for showing all images from document library but not images from specific folder inside a document library.