# Filtering List Rows into "Highlighted Content" on Home Page using CAML or KQL

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, caml-query, kql, highlighted-content-web-part

Edit: After more reading I think my first question becomes "Can you display a filtered list in Highlighted Content? If yes, can you use CAML or KQL to define the list(s) to filter and the filter itself?

Original Question:

I'm trying to build out some highlighted content in a SharePoint homepage (or other pages) that would be a list of specific rows out of another list in the SharePoint instance. The goal is to have a dashboard that pulls specific/filtered items out of separate lists to highlight the need for action. An example would be wanting to see items out of a "To-Do" list that are assigned to X employee AND are due in <= 10 days.

I'm familiar with SQL but now KQL or CAML. It's not clear to me how you target a specific list. In SQL it would be SELECT * FROM TABLE. In that case TABLE is the target. How do you specify in KQL or CAML which list you are wanting to target?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can use custom query with path like: `path:"https://siteUrl.com/Lists/ListName"`. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom query like below to get the list items from specific SharePoint list in highlighted content web part:

```
ContentClass:STS_ListItem Path: "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/Lists/ChildList"
```

[image]

**Similar thread**: [Highlighted Content custom query to find subdirectory contents](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/298758/highlighted-content-custom-query-to-find-subdirectory-contents)

Comment: Thank you for your time and the answer provided. 

When I use the query provided it's almost like the "Highlighted Content" is expecting to display documents - rather than rows out of the list...if that makes sense. The list I'm filtering doesn't have any documents, it's more of a To-do list. What I'm looking to do is display specific rows out of a list on a Home Page. I did see that you can create list views to get close but the filtering in list views is pretty basic. I was hoping to be able to use the Custom Query feature in "Highlighted Content" to really customize the filter of a list

Comment: I am not displaying any documents here. I am displaying items from SharePoint list. To change the UI in Highlighted content web part, you can use different layout from web part settings like **List** layout.

Comment: Hi @Spinach2121, does above solution help you in any way? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.